# How to create a common environment specific property file in javascript

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am new to programming in node.js. I want to know if there is a way to create a environment specific property file, the same way we create in java and read from there. Is there a similar way we can do it in node.js? I have to connect to the db and it has user, connect string and password. I need that to be environment specific.

Answer (score 1):

Most people use environment variables for environment-specific variables ;)

If you want to be able to supply those from a file, you can use the `dotenv` npm package to read defaults from a `.env` file, or you can use something like [direnv](https://direnv.net/) if you don't want to alter your code, and just want to be able to specify environment variables automatically depending on your working directory.

I'd say that `dotenv` is the common way to do this for development environments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You need .env files. See this guide for details: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nodejs-custom-env-files-in-your-apps-fa7b3e67abe1/